# Generated Windows store app package name looks strange

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I've set up my account and created my app (with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8). Now I'm at the point to associate it. So I use "Store > Associate App with the Store" and choose my reserved application name. Now I see what values will be transfered to my app. The value of "Package name" makes me wondering.

It looks like this: 12345MyName.MyAppName

So what is 12345? Why is the package name not "MyName.MyAppName"? If I look at "...\AppData\Local\Packages\" I can see that most of the other apps start with the company name and not some random number. So why is mine?

(How) Can I change that?

---

**Edit1:** Here's an example from already existing apps (you can install them from the store to see it for yourself):

- Blackjack Solitaire: 53543Nocodesoft.BlackjackSolitaire_...
- TuneIn Radio: TuneIn.TuneInRadio_...

Why did Nocodesoft receive a prefix while TuneIn didn't?
I want to get this straight *before* I release my first app.

---

**Edit2:**
The file Package.StoreAssociation.xml contains the string in question:

```
<NamespacePrefix>12345MyName</NamespacePrefix>
```

In the same file it's used as a part of "MainPackageIdentityName" and and in Package.appmanifest it's used in "Identity Name".

Of course I can change all that manually. But my reasonable fear is that it'll create problems in the official verification process causing trouble and a loss of time. Also I don't think that all the other app developers modified that manually. There must be some general configuration for the app or for the developer account that decides whether the NamespacePrefix is 12345MyName or MyName. But where?

Answer (score 1):

No. You Should not change that. That is unique name for your app .
For Android and ios we can specify that But for Windows Store Apps It's like

Comment: But have a look at the mentioned folder. Most of the app folders there don't have such a 5-digit-prefix. How come?

Comment: did you build it in local machine?

Comment: Once your app got live in store will shows that name. Until that it will shows the Uniqueid

Comment: My question is not about how the name will be shown in the store but how it's handled internally. There must be a difference between those apps/companies that receive a prefix and those that don't. Here's an example. Install the following 2 apps and see for yourself:
[Blackjack Solitaire: 53543Nocodesoft.BlackjackSolitaire_...]
[TuneIn Radio: TuneIn.TuneInRadio_...]
Apparently Nocodesoft received a prefix so all of their packages now start with a prefix. But most other don't. So what's the reason? I don't want my company name and thus the packages to have a prefix.

Comment: I agree, the prefix looks ugly :( and makes debugging more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Its all in app manifest. Try changing the package name . Only thing you need to be careful when you upload in the store try giving a proper name by changing the package name. I am not on my system but from mobile so sharing details. Of does not work leave a comment ill share the details to change. 
The name of the app.

Comment: Have you already successfully sent such a manually edited App to the verification process? My fear is that it'll cause problems. See my "Edit2" in the topic.

Comment: Yes my app is in the store with a 3 rating just because the client did no keep enuf free magazines to read. Your package name should reflect the same while uploading :) and remember after the app is in the store dont change the package name . You may get a certificate corrupt exception .

Comment: Well, I guess I just have to try it out. I'll do this next week and after I have a result I will write it here and rate your suggetion if it works.

Comment: Your solution already failed when I used "Tools > Create Package" for testing purposes. At this point the app was reassigned to the reserved app name and the prefix was automatically overwritten. If I did something wrong, please explain your solution in detail again.

Answer (score 0):

I e-mailed Microsoft about this, and here it what they said:

> The package name change that happens on your account when you are associating it with the online store is due to your pre-set publisher ID that was assigned to your account at the beginning.
>
> It's assigned to the publisher attribute of the package/identity element in the app's manifest.
>
> This piece of information is for internal use and it is not going to be visible on your app in Store at any place. It is for our records and stored as "friendly company name" - even if your account is an individual account.
>
> I'm afraid that we cannot change this feature on the account and as it is for to keep the package identified and linked to your account strictly I would not even recommend changing it if we had the option.
>
> I hope I could give you a reasonable explanation on what is happening on your account and why it is happening.

So even though "TuneIn.TuneInRadio_..." does have a nicely formatted package name, according to Microsoft's statement, we can't accomplish that.  "The package name change that happens on your account when you are associating it with the online store is due to your pre-set publisher ID that was assigned to your account at the beginning."

Comment: I believe that the "pretty names" in package IDs are used when you have a *company* account with the Store vs. an *individual* account.

Comment: I had a rather long communication with MS after posting the question here. First by email, later by phone. It all felt unbelievably mysterious. To sum up the information that I got:
1. It has nothing to do with company/individual account (look at the Packages folder and you'll see that it's absolutely random)
2. There's no publicly available info how to influence that ID
3. He's not allowed (!) to tell why e.g. TuneIn has no number in its package name. The whole conversation felt like "I know why but I can't tell you."

Comment: To be honest, little things like this discourage you to invest time in a new platform. I had a couple of other problems with Windows Store Apps as well. The thing is: they all seemed pretty random. And that's the worst that can happen. If you don't have the feeling that you have control over your project because of random, unexplainable external factors, you lose your motivation. And in my experience the whole Windows Store universe is random and unexplainable.